# Regular expression: Get 1234 from //test.test.com/test/1234/

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I have NSString - @"//test.test.com/test/1234/"

How I can check the string contains //test.test.com/test/ and get 1234?

I have tried -

```
 NSString *newstr = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

but it gets only numbers.

Maybe I need to use NSRegularExpressions? But how?

Comment: Can you explain in details what is the problem?

Comment: I need to check string for contain //test.test.com/test/  and get from it 1234

Comment: Use NSString's rangeOfString to know if exist or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the right-hand component of that string, then all you need to do is this...

```
NSString* str = @"//test.test.com/test/1234/";
NSString* newstr = [str lastPathComponent];     //  Returns "1234"
```

> How i can check string contain //test.test.com/test/ and get 1234 ?

If you *only* want to extract the last parameter if your string starts with `//test.test.com/test/` then, you can use this:

```
NSString* str = @"//test.test.com/test/1234/";
NSString* lastPart = @"";

if ([str rangeOfString:@"//test.test.com/test"].location != NSNotFound)
{
    lastPart = [str lastPathComponent];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps me -

```
NSString *pattern = @"//test.test.com/test/(\\d+)/";
            NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                          regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                          options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                          error:nil];
            NSTextCheckingResult *textCheckingResult = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

            NSRange matchRange = [textCheckingResult rangeAtIndex:1];
            NSString *match = [string substringWithRange:matchRange];
            NSLog(@"Found string '%@'", match);
```